# Форматирование списка в 4 столбика с помощью метода %. Python

Tags: python

не понимаю как можно применить такой способ форматирования для списка. У меня есть список их 50 элементов, мне нужно вывести его в 4 колонки с помощью метода %. Преподаватель сказал, воспользоваться циклом, но у меня не получается. Ниже прилагаю условие и код программы.

```
   #1. Пользователь вводит целое число n. Создать список
#из 50 элементов. Первые n значений — четные числа от 2 до
#2*n. Остальные элементы списка равны нулю. После этого
#вставить в середину списка элемент, равный 10*n. Вывести
#полученный список



n = int(input("Enter a number n<=50\nn= "))
while n>50:
   n = int(input("Error\nEnter a number n<=50\nn= "))
item_list=list(range(2,2*n+2,2))
while len(item_list)<50:
   item_list[n+1:50]+=[0]
item_list.insert((len(item_list))//2,10*n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Только, чтобы установить число ровно в середину нужно, чтобы было 51 элемент. i % 2 - проверяем на наличие четного элемента, если это нулевой элемент, то устанавливаем значение 2, последующие четные 2*i.
i % 2 возвращает остаток деления, если он 0, то число четное.
Нечетные устанавливаем значение в ноль.
Цикл for i in range(0 , n) делает итерации от 0 до n-1:
i = 0, i = 1, i = 3 и т.д. и последняя итерация к примеру если n = 50 будет i = 49.

```
arr = []
n = int(input("Enter a number n<=50\nn= "))

for i in range(0 , n):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        if i == 0:
            arr.append(2)
        else:
            arr.append(2*i)
    else:
        arr.append(0)
median = int(n/2)
arr[median] = 10*n
print(arr)
```